# Firebase "Permission denied" but still writes?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following ruleset for my Firebase app:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "EVENT_TABLE":{
            "$id":{
        //Explicitly allow for reading of the EVENT_TABLE item data, however specify sub-pieces to be unreadable.
        ".read":"auth != null",
        ".write":"auth != null",
        "allowed_users":{
          "$user_id":{

          }
                },
        "requested_users":{
           ".read":"auth != null",
           ".write":"auth != null"
        }
      }
    },
    "EVENT_TABLE_GEO_MAP":{
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "EVENT_CONFIDENTIALS_TABLE":{
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "$id":{
        ".read": "root.child('EVENT_TABLE/'+$id+'/allowed_users/'+auth.uid).exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever a user tries to add themselves to the "requested_users" map under the EVENT_TABLE object, it says "Permission Denied" but still successfully writes the user's ID.

Here is the example data:

```
{
  "b216d166-eff2-4947-898c-cef75e32605e" : {
    "allowed_users" : {
      "gEnCx9TIFNNOjExbzEtdIBwB2t62" : 1
    },
    "body" : "ahah",
    "end" : 1490842878378,
    "id" : "b216d166-eff2-4947-898c-cef75e32605e",
    "latitude" : 44.783728,
    "longitude" : -93.2468524,
    "name" : "New Event",
    "owner_id" : "gEnCx9TIFNNOjExbzEtdIBwB2t62",
    "requested_users" : {
      "0G4OMRWeiNScz5KnpkOaDQw9kd02" : 1
    },
    "start" : 1490842876140
  }
}
```

After a user has requested to write a new Map containing their id to the 'requested_users' field.

Furthermore, here is the function I used in Android to call the write:

```
  public static void requestToJoinEvent(Event eventRequested, final Activity activityCalling){

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(user!=null){
            retrieveDatabaseReference(EVENT_TABLE);
            eventRequested.getRequested_users().put(user.getUid(),1);
            ref.child(eventRequested.getId()).child("requested_users").setValue(eventRequested.getRequested_users());
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    operationSuccess=true;
                    displayRequestSentMessage(activityCalling);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    //This returns with a Permission Denied error.
                }
            });
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException("User is missing!");
        }
    }
```

Why is it throwing a Permission Denied error and still successfully writing?

Comment: I'm having the same problem